# Can we add multiple attributes to a node in a single LDAP operation

Tags: performance, ldap, openldap, tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

suppose I have a node like user in LDAP and I want to multiple attributes to it in one LDAP operation i.e. single update operation.Is it possible?

Any pointers would be helpful.

**Note :** I am using TDS.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, something like:

```
dn: cn=Barney Fife,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: telephonenumber
telephonenumber: 555-1212
telephonenumber: 555-6789
-
add: manager
manager: cn=Sally Nixon,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
```

Many examples can be found from google ldif examples.

I assume TDS is Tivoli Directory Server and this should work fine.

-jim

Comment: Thanks jeemster, will try out this